# Raspberry SSH works on Linux but access denied on Windows 10

Tags: pi-3, ssh, raspbian-stretch

I can login with `ssh my_username@192.168.0.5` when I use Ubuntu 16.04.

However 
using Windows 10, it says

PuTTY:

`Network error: Permission denied`.

Windows Power Shell:

`> ssh my_username@192.168.0.5`

`ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.5 port 22: Permission denied`

Comment: Is the Windows machine on the same sub-network?

Comment: Are you using the standard ssh port (port 22) for the ssh server on your pi?

Comment: Yes to both questions. Windows is on the same sub-network and I am using port 22.

Comment: Is the Windows Firewall enabled and permitting outgoing connections from `ssh`?

Comment: Port 22 for SSH is in the monitored ports in Kaspersky. https://support.kaspersky.com/us/11589

Comment: so are you saying that kaspersky is blocking the request?

Comment: have you tried some simple debugging - `ssh -vvv my_username@192.168.0.5`

Comment: I suggest to enable logging in putty and check the putty log. In addition you can check on the other side (Raspberry) /var/log/syslog  for error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also new here and can't comment, so the only way to communicate is an "answer", I think. Which is: when ssh:d to your PI (from your linux environ then), you can check the authentication log for sshd:

```
cat /var/log/auth.log | grep "sshd"
```

it tends to keep details on connection attempts.

Comment: The Windows connection attempt is not written to log. Only successful attempts from Ubuntu and iOS are visible there.

Comment: Aha, it does sound like a network issue then. If you are behind a router firewall I would disable Kaspersky and whatever else software firewall, the Windows one for example, might be running, for only a minute, then attempt to connect, just to establish that software on Windows isn't blocking the outbound connection.

Comment: And you can of course make sure that other hosts are reachable by the same putty program, and perhaps test WinSCP : )